# GitHub desktop not showing remote branches

Tags: github

GitHub (version 3.0.5.2) for Windows no longer shows me all the remote branches. This is working with a GitHub for Enterprise server.

For example, when I click on the branches drop down, it used to show me all the remote branches in origin, but now only shows me branches I’ve checked out locally.

Is this a bug or is there some setting adjustment I need to make?

Answer (score 35):

Hit **F5** on your keyboard.

You won't see anything, but it should fetch your remote branches.

Comment: I wonder why they don't add it to the GUI. But it works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I wonder how you discovered it tho hahaha

Comment: F5 refreshes your browser, so I tried it ;-)

Comment: Since this works within the desktop app without having to go over to Git Shell, I think this is the best answer since OP was asking specifically about the desktop app.

Comment: @Jack mind explaining how you figure this out? Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Odys it was just a lucky guess, because F5 is an old convention for refreshing things.

Answer (score 27):

You could try:

```
git fetch
```

Run this from within the directory that contains your local repository. Fetching from a repository grabs all the new remote-tracking branches and tags without merging those changes into your own branches.

This is a command that you can make via the command prompt in a command window. To use it you need to install a git CLI (Command Line Interface) - which lets you issue manual git commands.

Comment: Exactly what was needed, good answer.

Comment: Any ideas why there isn't a GUI way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` doesn't always to the trick it seems. If you know the name of the branch you could just simply `git checkout <branch-name>`. If you enter the name correctly you'll be switched to that branch.